# How to fix "mount: 'remount'->'/system': No such file or directory"?

Tags: mount, command-line

```
angler:/ # mount -o rw, remount /system
mount: 'remount'->'/system': No such file or directory
1|angler:/ #
```

When I try in Kali Linux in my phone:

```
root@kali:~# mount -o rw, remount /system
mount: /system: special device remount does not exist.
root@kali:~#
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  have added a space between the two options you passed: `rw` and `remount`. You need to remove space after the comma `,` and then repeat the command like this:

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

This should work. Tested on OnePlus 6.

Comment: Ups yes that was it. Thx :)